# Number of homeomorphism types of separable closed subspaces of $\beta \mathbb N$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

When thinking about subalgebras of $\ell_\infty$, the algebra of bounded, scalar-valued, I came across the following question related to counting subalgebras with weak*-separable dual ball obtainable by restricting to closed subsets of the spectrum of $\ell_\infty$.

> Let $\beta \mathbb N$ be the Čech–Stone compactification of the discrete space of natural numbers. How many pairwise non-homeomorphic closed and **separable** subspaces does $\beta \mathbb N$ have?

Such subspaces cannot be second-countable unless finite, but there are many separable closed subspaces (take the closure of any countable subset) and there is no obvious way to classify them up to homeomorphism.

Comment: Do you know how many second-countable ones does it have? It amounts to finding the countably generated quotients of the algebra of clopen sets, I think. I'm not sure whether separability translates to any easy to understand algebraic condition.

Comment: @tomasz, they cannot be secound-countable, unless finite for Banach-space reasons.

Comment: Why has this question been closed? I'm new to this forum, but can absolutely not understand, why it should not meet the guidelines? Could the one who closed it, please explain?

Comment: @Ulli: I did not vote to close myself, but think this is the lack of any commentary/preliminary observations or motivations on OP's side.

Comment: What kind of commentary besides "I am curious whether..." would fit here?

Comment: Closing this question is ridiculous. It’s a highly non-trivial question asked by an experienced mathematician.

Comment: I am in agreement with the close voters, who indicated that this question lacks context.  This question is,  in the parlance of this site, a Problem Statement Question---it consists of a problem statement, and no additional information.  Such a question does not meet the [context standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for this site.

Comment: @XanderHenderson; I have added some useless sentences; hope the question meets the context standards now.

Comment: @TomaszKania: I agree that the "context" requirements are ridiculous in this case but making a fuss about it in the question body is only going to attract more negative attention.  I hope you don't mind that I've cleaned it up a little.

Comment: @TomaszKania I appreciate your willingness to improve your question by adding some context.  I will add, for future reference, that "this is what I tried..." *is* a rather useless kind of context, and I don't think that anyone was suggesting that you add in "an attempt".

Comment: The beginning of a possible "reduction" of the problem: A closed set in $\beta\mathbb N$ is given by a filter $F$ on $\mathbb N$, namely as the intersection of the closures (in $\beta\mathbb N$) of the sets in $F$. And separability says that $F$ is the intersection of countably many ultrafilters. But I haven't (yet) made homeomorphism look combinatorial.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Homeomorphism would say that the quotients of $P(\mathbb{N})$ by the filters are isomorphic.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks. I should have realized that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are exactly $2^c$ pairwise nonhomeomorphic separable closed subspaces in $\beta \mathbb N$.**

The proof is essentially just a reference to a great paper:

Since $|\beta \mathbb N| = 2^c$, there are $2^c$ countable subsets in $\beta \mathbb N$, hence $\beta \mathbb N$ has only $2^c$ separable subspaces.

The other, non-trivial, direction is mainly the Main Theorem in
[A. Dow, A.V. Gubbi, A. Szymanski, "Rigid Stone Spaces within ZFC"](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1988-102-03/S0002-9939-1988-0929014-4/S0002-9939-1988-0929014-4.pdf): 
*There exist $2^c$ pairwise nonhomeomorphic rigid separable Stone spaces*, 
where Stone space is (in this paper) an extremally disconnected compact Hausdorff space.
As it is well-known, each separable extremally disconnected space can be embedded into $\beta \mathbb N$
(see, for instance, Corollary 3.2 [here](https://msp.org/pjm/1976/65-2/pjm-v65-n2-p27-p.pdf)).

*Remark*: Perhaps there might be much easier constructions, since here we don't need that the spaces are rigid
(= the only autohomeomorphism is the identity).